# Uninstall python.org version of python2.7 in favor of default OS X python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, osx-mountain-lion

I'm running OS X 10.8.2 and I believe that by default this comes with Python 2.7.3. I previously had Python 2.7.2 installed from python.org and would like to scrap it to basically reset my system's default python to that which comes pre-installed. The reason being that whenever I launch any *.py file IDLE refuses to open (even when specifying my installed Python2.7.2 IDLE) and I want to get things up to date.

Although I never use it, I do have MacPorts installed and I'm seeing that it did a bunch of stuff to my Python path - notably changing my Python 2.7 path to "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}", so I don't know if this makes a difference.

Can anybody recommend a course of action here? I'm happy to provide additional information if needed.

Comment: I would like to answer this, but unfortunately I have no idea. You've treaded in dangerous waters, installing multiple versions of things on OS X. Perhaps try looking on the install DVD/image to see if there's an installer for the original python?

Comment: Yeah I'm in pretty deep here unfortunately. I'm pretty sure that the python install just comes bundled with OS X and isn't available independently..I could always reformat and just restore my documents/user, but I'm afraid of losing too much and that I would just be wasting my time

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are three things making up the python.org python install which need to be removed. These steps worked for me:

1. Remove the actual Python install:

   ```
   rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
   ```
2. Remove the Python.org extra applications by deleting the folder at `/Applications/Python 2.7`:

   ```
   rm -rf /Applications/Python\ 2.7
   ```
3. Remove the symlinks to the python executables from your `/usr/local/bin` directory:

   ```
   find /usr/local/bin -type l -and -lname "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework*" -delete
   ```
4. Remove or comment out these lines from your bash startup script (either `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`):

   ```
   # Setting PATH for Python 2.7
   # The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
   PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
   export PATH
   ```

Some of these steps may require super-user privileges via e.g. `sudo`. Once this is done, you should have only the original Mac.

*Based on documentation at http://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html*

Comment: Golden answer. The official doc reads: "To uninstall MacPython, you can simply remove these three things." Confusingly, "these things" refers both to the prior bullet, the prior sentence, and the sentence _after_. Thanks for clearing "things" up. P.S. On Python 2.6, the `/usr/local/bin` symlinks were relative, so my `-lname` parameter in step 3 was just `"*Python.framework*"`. I ran without `-delete` first to be sure it would delete only what was intended.

Comment: Could you add to your answer: 'What to do if one gets Permission denied error while execution rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework"

Comment: I had to modify the step #3 to /usr/bin instead of /usr/local/bin/. I had both 2.7 and 3.7 installed. The 3.7 got deleted properly. However, I still have python2.7 information in /usr/bin after step 3. "pydoc             python            python2.7         pythonw           
pydoc2.7          python-config     python2.7-config  pythonw2.7  "

Comment: @Valentyn Don't mess with macOS installed Python in /usr/bin! That said, I also had to modify step 3 because the symlinks to the framework were relative. So used `-lname "../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework*"` instead.