# Django: ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest

Tags: python, django, macos

I have installed Django 1.6.5 with PIP and Python 2.7.8 from the website.

I ran `django-admin.py startproject test123`, switched to `test123` directory, and ran the command `python manage.py runserver`, then i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 50, in _setup
    self._configure_logging()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 72, in _configure_logging
    from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/utils/log.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter, get_exception_reporter_filter
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/views/debug.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.http import (HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/http/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.http.request import (HttpRequest, QueryDict, UnreadablePostError,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/http/request.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.core import signing
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/signing.py", line 45, in <module>
    from django.utils.crypto import constant_time_compare, salted_hmac
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/utils/crypto.py", line 6, in <module>
    import hmac
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 8, in <module>
    from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest
ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest
```

Found out that operator is a standard python library. Why cant it not import it?

P.S. I did try it in the command line, I can import the operator module, but I get an error on this statement: `from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Followed this SO answer: 
[Uninstall python.org version of python2.7 in favor of default OS X python2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538586/uninstall-python-org-version-of-python2-7-in-favor-of-default-os-x-python2-7)

Then changed my `.bash_profile` Python path to `/usr/lib/python` for the default OSX python path.

Uninstalled Django and MySQL-Python:

```
sudo pip uninstall django
sudo pip uninstall MySQL-Python
```

And then again reinstalled everything, but with `MySQL-Python` being the first and second Django.

After these steps, everything is working.

Comment: I think this happens because of `virtualenv`. So do this to recover the `virtualenv`.            `virtualenv /path-to/env-folder` - I got it from debian mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

I get this error with anaconda as my default python and django1.7 while trying to use startproject.
I deleted the venv and recreated it with

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
```

startproject was working again.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have another file named `operator.py` on your `PYTHONPATH` (probably in the current working directory), which shadows the standard library `operator` module..

Remove or rename the file.

Comment: How would I check if I do? This is a new install of the OS, and I havent created any new files or projects of any sort. Only a first run of Django.

Comment: @Edvinauskas run this from the command line: `python -c "import operator; print operator.__file__"`. This should tell you which file is getting imported.

Comment: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so`

Comment: It resides here... Should I try to remove it? But could it looks to be as a default installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

For those not wanting to switch to Apple's python, simply [deleting the virtualenv and rebuilding it](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=749491#10) worked fine for me.

Tip:  Don't forget to `pip freeze > requirements.txt` first if you aren't already tracking your package requirements.  That way you can `pip install -r requirements.txt` to get up and running again quickly.