# Python/Flask error: "ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest"

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

With Windows, I am following [this Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) when I came across the following error:

```
C:\Users\Gregory Gundersen\Documents\Research\flask-test>python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "C:\Users\Gregory Gundersen\Documents\Research\flask-test\app\__init__.py
", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import json
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\json.py", line 25, in <module>
    from itsdangerous import json as _json
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous.py", line 14, in <module>
    import hmac
  File "C:\Python27\lib\hmac.py", line 8, in <module>
    from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest
ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest
```

There are [SO questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853027/django-importerror-cannot-import-name-compare-digest), but they are for OS X/Django. Has anyone see or resolved this issue for PC/Flask before?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv with your project? More information in the [installation documentation for flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/installation/)

Comment: @Doobeh, thanks. I tried to executing `distribute_setup.py`, which I hadn't done—but I had used that page to install `easy_install` and `pip`. When I just use `pip`, I do get another error: `C:\Python27\lib\distutils\__init__.py:14: UserWarning: The virtualenv distutils
package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils? "The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?")`.

Comment: Seems to be an odd error-- is this the first time you've worked with Python?  I'm wondering if it'd be easier to just uninstall Python-- then try a more packaged solution like [ActiveState Python](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) which (at least last time I used it) includes pip and sets up the environment path correctly (rather then you having to manually do so).

Comment: It looks like you have a local module `operator.py` and it is masking the standard library module. What does `import operator; print operator` produce?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters:

`>>> import operator
>>> print operator
<module 'operator' (built-in)>
>>> operator.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'`

Comment: @ggundersen: yet when you run for Flask project you *do* have such a module masking the built-in. Are you certain your `sys.path` is the same as when you run your Flask project?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I'm not certain. Could you outline how I should check this or point me to a resource?

Comment: @ggundersen: add the lines to your `run.py` and see what turns up then. Or catch the `ImportError` exception and print `sys.modules['operator']` to see if that is still the built-in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it looks like it is built-in in the exception: `Traceback (most recent call last): mFile "flask-test.py", line 6, in <module> raise Exception(sys.modules['operator']) Exception: <module 'operator' (built-in)>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63592/discussion-between-martijn-pieters-and-ggundersen).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You appear to have *half* the changes made for [issue 21306 (backporting hmac.compare_digest to 2.7)](http://bugs.python.org/issue21306).

Your `hmac` module has the lines:

```
from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest
```

at the top, but your `sys.version_info` shows you are running Python 2.7.6; quoting our quick chat session:

> Me: Next simple check:
>
> ```
> import sys
> print(sys.version_info)
> ```
>
> You: `sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

The `hmac` version you have is for [Python 2.7.7](https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/f89216059edf/Misc/NEWS) and up, however!

You'll want to reinstall your Python; download 2.7.8 and reinstall it to make sure you have the correct binary executable for your standard library files.

Comment: This required some serious yak shaving of an old PC I inherited at work; thanks for hoping on a chat to help. After uninstalling Python 2.7 and Python 2.6 from the machine, I noticed that `sys.executable` was pointing to an Enthought distribution of Python, I removed that version of Python as well, reinstalled Python 2.7.8, and then verified that `sys.version_info`'s "micro" property was 8 and the binary was correct. The Flask server now starts. Thanks!

Comment: Just had the same problem on 2.7.9, but on closer inspection it turns out I had three versions of 2.7 installed simultaneously. Just breaking out the firefighter's axe right now....

Comment: Also had the same problem on 2.7.9, tried reinstalling but didn't work. I then noticed that after uninstalling the C:/Python27/Python27.dll was still there. I deleted it, installed Python again and now it works.

Comment: Related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366415/python-module-masking-from-operator-import-compare-digest-as-compare-digest)

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I've just installed python 2.7.9 from source and set it to path in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/bin`. I think it is easier if I reinstall `hmac` again. How can I check my `hmac` version?

Comment: @yellow01: I checked the [Python 2.7 `hmac` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/2.7/Lib/hmac.py) (link to the 'blame' view which shows where specific lines come from).

Answer (score 4):

This can occur when you have updated python without rebuilding your virtualenv.  In this case, just regenerate your virtualenv.