# Need help on getting started with google app engine(PYTHON 2.7)

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine

I've installed GAE in my computer(windows 7 64-bit). But whenever I click run on the program it doesn't work, and when I use the command line using dev_appserver.py this happens "dev_appserver.py is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". What should I do?

edit1: Here's the log error when I'm using the program.

[image: Error MESSAGE]

edit2: Here's my full python path

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;c:\users\jansen\appdata\local\enthought\canopy32\user\scripts;C:\Users\jansen\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User;C:\Users\jansen\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\vtk;C:\Python27\gnuplot\binary;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\SciTE-3.5.1-4;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\console;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\swig;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\gettext\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again?

Comment: I tried making a new application and made the path to my desktop. Then click the run icon. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Note, after reading your update please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/26550917/501494

Answer (score 2):

dev_appserver.py is the web server that is distributed with the google appengine sdk. You would run this after you have created an application.

If the command dev_appserver.py is not recognized you need to either add to your Path environment variable the location of the cloud sdk:

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin
```

Or specify the full path to dev_appserver when you're running it:

```
python C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\dev_appserver.py
```

For a larger primer I would suggest walking through the provided tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

UPDATE:
Your updated question actually has nothing to do with dev_appserver but your python installation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26550917/501494

Comment: python C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py
python: can't open file "C:\Program": [Errno2] No file in such directory. I do think ur right tho.

Comment: There are varying installation locations.  Locate yours and you should be good.

Comment: I don't have a bin folder tho. What's the difference of ur first statement to the second one?

Comment: The error is because missing quotes `python "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\dev_appserver.py"`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JaimeGómez but this is what what happens when it did it. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2h71dgh&s=8#.VRzSbZNozs0. I don't think  GAE will start.

Comment: Something is wrong with your installation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535043/python-flask-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-compare-digest might help.