# Python Virtualenv Missing Package

Tags: python, python-2.7, chef-infra, virtualenv, uwsgi

Using Chef and the [Python](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/python) cookbook I have set up a virtualenv with version 2.7.9 of python but I am getting the following error:

```
  File "/var/www/ediflo/cms/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
  File "/var/www/ediflo/cms/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .sessions import SecureCookieSessionInterface
  File "/var/www/ediflo/cms/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 14, in <module>
    from werkzeug.contrib.securecookie import SecureCookie
  File "/var/www/ediflo/cms/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/securecookie.py", line 93, in <module>
    from hmac import new as hmac
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 8, in <module>
    from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest
ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest
```

Any know why this is happening or how it can be fixed?

Edit:

If I run python from the virtualenv in interactive mode I can run `from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest` without issue.

Edit:

Having looked at the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535043/python-flask-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-compare-digest) I don't think it is a duplicate. I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04, when I run through the commands provided in that answer, checking the details of the install, the output of `sys.version_info` is `sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`.

Printing operator shows the following:

```
>>> import operator
>>> print operator
<module 'operator' from '/var/www/app/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so'>
```

Looking at that path it is a symlink to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload`.

Printing hmac shows the following:

```
>>> import hmac
>>> print hmac
<module 'hmac' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hmac.pyc'>
```

Comment: It seems your Python installation is corrupted somehow. You might want to run the recipe again.

Comment: Thanks @BurhanKhalid, I'll check out the duplicate question. I have run the recipe multiple times but it's always the same result.

Comment: Maybe it is something to do with uWSGI.

Comment: As it turns out this is happening due to the Ubuntu uwsgi-plugin-python package. To get around this issue either install uwsgi via pip or build it your self. If the question is re-opened I'll put this in as an answer.