# Python/Flask error: “ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest”

Tags: python, flask

I run linux mint 17.2 XCFE on my computer.

My issue is nearly identical to [the one found in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535043/python-flask-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-compare-digest), except I tried all of the solutions offered and none worked. It's worth noting that as a result of me trying to fiddle with python, my machine now runs 2.7.8 and the venv runs 2.7.6, which is easy to fix but might be relevant.

I also consulted [this](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1212) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853027/django-importerror-cannot-import-name-compare-digest), and tried changing the name of file called operator and a different virtualenv command as suggested in those, but nothing worked. (Note: I then changed the name of that file back to operator just because since that wasn't the problem I'd rather not mess with it).

When I try to run a [very simple script for flask newbs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) I keep encountering the same error.

```
(venv)joshua@joshua-ThinkPad-Edge-E430 ~/website/projects/helloapp $ python hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/home/joshua/website/projects/helloapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
  File "/home/joshua/website/projects/helloapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import json
  File "/home/joshua/website/projects/helloapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 25, in <module>
    from itsdangerous import json as _json
  File "/home/joshua/website/projects/helloapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 14, in <module>
    import hmac
  File "/home/joshua/anaconda/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 8, in <module>
    from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest
ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest
```

I have been trying to figure out a solution on my own for hours but I've had no luck. I think it might have to do with Anaconda but I'm not sure what could be done if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out the issue was that the hmac.py file had a reference to a method that it appears no longer existed. I disabled that reference with '#' (just incase it turns out it was important) and it started working.

Comment: which line did you comment out in hmac.py?

Comment: Commented out this line:  `from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest` in `hmac.py` which for me was in `/Anaconda2/Lib/`